# React hooks updating array is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm currently learning hook, and I'm writing a todo-list:

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Item from './components/Item';
function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const addTask = (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'Enter'){
      let newTask = {content: e.target.value, completed: false};
      console.log(newTask);
      setTasks(prevTask => {
        return ([...prevTask, newTask]);
      });  
      console.log(tasks);
    }
  }

  const completeTask = (e) =>{
    let newTask = tasks.slice();
    newTask[e].completed = !tasks[e].completed;
    setTasks(newTask);
  }

  const deleteTask = (e) => {
    let newTask = tasks.slice();
    newTask.splice(e);
    setTasks(newTask);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <header className="todo-app__header">
        <h1 className="todo-app__title">todos</h1>
      </header>
      <section className="todo-app__main">
        <input className="todo-app__input" placeholder="What needs to be done?" onKeyDown={addTask}/>
        <ul className="todo-app__list" id="todo-list">
          {tasks.map(item => <Item num = {tasks.indexOf(item)} text={item.content} completed = {item.completed} 
          onClick = {completeTask(tasks.indexOf(item))} delete = {deleteTask(tasks.indexOf(item))}/>)}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, adding tasks is not working!!
The newTask printed is well, but it doesn't push into the tasks array.
The tasks is still empty.

What's the problem?
Also, another problem: is it related to `useeffect`? I don't know what `useeffect` is used for.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that every time your component renders, it executes both `completeTask` and `deleteTask`, because you are using function *calls* as props. You need to be passing in a function *object* or expression. Instead of telling the component to execute `completeTask` on click, the function call just executes it right there as soon as the component is rendered.

The problem is with this part of your code:

```
<ul className="todo-app__list" id="todo-list">
    {tasks.map(item => <Item num = {tasks.indexOf(item)} text={item.content} completed = {item.completed} 
    onClick = {completeTask(tasks.indexOf(item))} delete = {deleteTask(tasks.indexOf(item))}/>)}
 </ul>
```

The following lines:

```
delete = {deleteTask(tasks.indexOf(item))}
```

```
onClick = {completeTask(tasks.indexOf(item))}
```

Should be changed to:

```
delete = {() => deleteTask(tasks.indexOf(item))}
```

```
onClick = {() => completeTask(tasks.indexOf(item))}
```

In normal HTML, it would look like `delete="deleteFunction()"`, but in React, it should be `delete={deleteFunction}`, because writing a function with parenthesis after it is a function *call*, not a function *expression*. If you need to pass in an argument, you can either pass the argument in as a prop on the component, or change the line to `delete={() => deleteFunction(arg)}`, as the parenthesis and arrow makes it a function expression.

See Handling Events: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code **works well** and there is no problem.

React `setState` action in async. Try to log it in `useEffect`.

```js
const App = () = => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(tasks)
    }, [tasks]);

    const addTask = () => {
        const newTask = {...};
        setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
    }
}
```

[useEffect Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Answer (score 0):

Here as I can see, you are doing `console.log(tasks)` in the same function.
Try the `console.log(tasks)` outside function and you will see `tasks` array with the values you entered.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
function Add() {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
    const addTask = (e) => {
        if(e.key === 'Enter'){
            let newTask = {content: e.target.value, completed: false};
            console.log(newTask);
            setTasks(prevTask => {
               return ([...prevTask, newTask])
            });
            console.log(tasks);
        }
    }

    const completeTask = (e) =>{
        let newTask = tasks.slice();
        newTask[e].completed = !tasks[e].completed;
        setTasks(newTask);
    }

    const deleteTask = (e) => {
        let newTask = tasks.slice();
        newTask.splice(e);
        setTasks(newTask);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <header className="todo-app__header">
                <h1 className="todo-app__title">todos</h1>
            </header>
            <section className="todo-app__main">
                <input className="todo-app__input" placeholder="What needs to be done?" onKeyDown={addTask}/>
                <ul className="todo-app__list" id="todo-list">
                    {tasks.map((item)=> <li>{item.content}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </section>
        </>
    );
}

export default Add;
```

it works very well and that means your Item component is your problem.